# jQuery: Where to insert the .animate step function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm trying to modify a library called [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) in order to output to the console the value of every animation step while the animation is taking place.

This is the actual function that manages the animation:

```
$(scrolledElement).animate(scrollOptions, options.scrollingSpeed, options.easing, function () {
    continuousVerticalFixSectionOrder();
    $.isFunction(options.afterLoad) && !localIsResizing && options.afterLoad.call(this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1));
    setTimeout(function () {
        isMoving = false;
        $.isFunction(callback) && callback.call(this);
    }, scrollDelay);
});
```

My step function would be something like this:

```
step: function(){
    var currentTop = $("#superContainer").offset().top;
    console.log( "Left: ", currentTop );
};
```

I tried lots of combinations but still haven't guessed where to put it without breaking the code.

Sorry to bother, I guess it's a noob question, but I spent 4 hours on it without results.
Thanks everyone!

Achille

Comment: Without modifying the core, good luck!

Comment: Really? This [manual](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) says it's just a setting to add in the animate parameters...

Comment: I mean't without modifying the core of the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this section in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options):

```
.animate( properties, options )
```

`properties` and `options` are two objects and `steps` has to be a property on `options`. So your code becomes

```
$(scrolledElement).animate(
    scrollOptions, 
    {
       duration: options.scrollingSpeed,
       easing: options.easing,
       step: function() {
          // ...
       },
       complete: function () {
          continuousVerticalFixSectionOrder();
          // ...
       }
    }
);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much, I got lost while trying to understand the documentation! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
            $(scrolledElement).animate(
                scrollOptions
            , { step: function(){
                        var currentTop = $("#superContainer").offset().top;
                        console.log( "Left: ", currentTop );
                        }
            }, options.scrollingSpeed, options.easing, function () {
                //fix section order from continuousVertical
                continuousVerticalFixSectionOrder();

                //callback (afterLoad) if the site is not just resizing and readjusting the slides
                $.isFunction(options.afterLoad) && !localIsResizing && options.afterLoad.call(this, anchorLink, (sectionIndex + 1));

                setTimeout(function () {
                    isMoving = false;
                    $.isFunction(callback) && callback.call(this);
                }, scrollDelay);
            });
```

Enjoy,
Rocco

Comment: Everything worked apart from the last setTimeout, thank you alot anyways !